# AndroidStudio: java. How can i return an arraylist to main activity?

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist, android-intent

**I tried this way:**
The application stops working on setResult only when the arraylist is not empty.
**SECONDARY ACTIVITY**

```
Intent d = new Intent();
d.putExtra("cat",(Serializable)  category.categories);
setResult(RESULT_OK, d);
finish();
```

**CATEGORIES INITIALIZATION:**

```
public ArrayList<buy_categories2> categorie= new ArrayList<buy_categories2>();
```

**MAIN ACTIVITY**
in the method onActivityResult:

```
ArrayList<buy_categories2> b2 = new ArrayList<buy_categories2>();
b2 = (ArrayList<buy_categories2>) data.getExtras().getSerializable("cat");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`buy_categories2` must be `Serializable`